# Set grid height

Tags: css, css-grid

`height: 100%` didn't work on grid container

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    background-color: red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    height: 100%;
    /* min-height: 100vh; */
}
```

Devtool shows that the body takes up all available space but the container didn't. Specifying `min-height: 100vh;` did the job but why didn't the prior option work?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post a working [repro]. CSS alone is useless in most cases without its corresponding HTML markup.

Comment: You can't apply `height:100%` to something with only a min-height

Comment: vh is "really" sizing: 100vh is the height of your window. If it was 500px height, 1vh is 5px: a real value. 100% alone (mainly if nothing in, or only background image) is 100% of what? of nothing in fact: so no height. You can calculate the computed height of the body, but the css won't apply this way.

Comment: @pierfarrugia you're technically incorrect. `100%` means 100% of the parent's height. That however requires the parent to have a defined height. If the height is undefined then 100% of undefined equals undefined.

Comment: @tacoshy, hehe more or less. In fact I was saying exactly same as you (another way): 100% of nothing is nothing

Comment: @pierfarrugia your explanation is incorrect because 100% is completely valid. It just requires an element in the DOM that has a defined height so that the 100% can be calculated. It doesn't care about the content just about the height of the parent element (or in case the parent is 100% as well the next parent element).